# GDI+ Bitmap LockBits returns rotated image?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi+, lockbits

I loaded an image from file and want to write it to AVI file:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap frame(L"test.png", FALSE);
Gdiplus::BitmapData bmp_data = {};
Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, frame.GetWidth(), frame.GetHeight());
frame.LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, frame.GetPixelFormat(), 
    &bmp_data);
AVIStreamWrite(avi_stream, i, 1, bmp_data.Scan0, 
    std::abs(bmp_data.Stride) * bmp_data.Height, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, NULL, NULL);
frame.UnlockBits(&bmp_data);
```

Resulting avi-file is rotated by 180 degrees. What's wrong?

Also I noticed that original image was bottom-up (`Bitmap::LockBits()` returned negative `BitmapData::Stride`). I saved it to disk by `Bitmap::Save()`. After loading the image is top-down.

Comment: This is normal, bitmaps are stored upside-down.  You'll have to copy the image one scanline at a time.

Comment: @Andy T: What Hans meant was to recompose another top-down buffer by copying one scanline at a time from the buffer returned by `LockBits`, then pass the new buffer to `AVIStreamWrite`. Alternatively, you could configure your AVI stream itself to use a bottom-up bitmap format.

Comment: @casablanca: how AVI stream can be configured to take bottom-up format? I'm setting AVI stream format by `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. Tried to specify negative `biHeight`, this doesn't helps.

Comment: manual rearrangement of scanlines work. I would accept this answer if it was not a comment. also very interested if this memory copying can be avoided by AVI stream format

Comment: @Hans @Andy @casablanca You should be able to use a negative value of height somewhere along the way to say that you want to interpret the bitmap the other way up. I just don't know where to apply the trick.

Comment: @Andy T: Exactly what @David said -- you must be passing a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` somewhere to set up your AVI stream. At that point, you can pass a negative height to indicate a bottom-up bitmap.

Comment: @casablanca, @david: yeah, I tried this with `AVIStreamSetFormat`, as commented earlier. nothing changed